# Share interface between main and test maven

Tags: java, maven

In my application I have interface which certain classes should follow, I want to write test code using the same interface

It follows maven conventions where main code lies

src/main/java

and test lies in

src/test/java

Currently I am not able to implement the interface in my test file

Comment: What is the problem? Code in `src/test/java` has access to classes in `src/main/java`, so that should just work if your interface is in packages under `src/main/java`...

Comment: updated the question

Comment: have you written any test code? is it not compiling? can you post the compilation error?

Comment: Why would you like to implement an interface from `src/main/java` in `src/test/java`?

Answer (score 0):

The test classes should import the interface if they are not in the same package.  If the test is in the same package structure, there's no need to import - they have access by default.

The Maven structure does not restrict classpath access.